# Cannot render Handlebars views in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

So i have been trying to follow some guides online to debug and fix my situation however it keeps not loading anything. so here i am to ask you guys if there is something wrong with the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var apiOptions = {
  useRedis: false,
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379,
  cacheTTL: 7200
};
var lolapi = require('lolapi')('4df431ee-5631-4db3-b7d5-771c8aaf02f0', 'oce', apiOptions);
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Welcome to Api' });
});
```

Comment: the index file has content of {{title}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [documentation](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)
you need to have the structure

```
.
├── app.js
└── views
    ├── home.handlebars
    └── layouts
        └── main.handlebars
```

then set **views/layouts/main.handlebars**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example App</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

and you index.handlebars in **views/index.handlebars**

```
<h1>App Title: {{{title}}}</h1>
```